# xml parsing in python: how to capture child's text when it is placed after grandchildren in the xml tree

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

How can I get the text "it" from this `xml` sample using `xml` parser for `python`?

```
<EXP ID="2">
    <W>
        love
        <EXP ID="1">
            <PTR src="0" />
            it
        </EXP>
    </W>
</EXP>
```

Here is what I tried:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET    
r = ET.fromstring(sample)
for c in r:
    print (c.tag, c.attrib, c.text)
    for d in c:
        print (d.tag, d.attrib, d.text)
```

The output for this:

```
W {} love
EXP {'ID': '1'}
```

But it should be:

```
W {} love
EXP {'ID': '1'} it
```

I get the expected result if the word "it" was placed before the sub tag:

```
<EXP ID="2">
    <W>
        love
        <EXP ID="1">
            it
            <PTR src="0" />
        </EXP>
    </W>
</EXP>
```

How can I get the same output from the original `xml` doc; text is placed after sub children?

Comment: the right way to use PTR tag is as shown in your second example because it's a pointer...

Comment: I have to parse the documents the way they are; I am not writing the document myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ElementTree model text node that comes after (following sibling of) an element is stored as `tail` of that element. So the text node 'it' in this case can be accessed from `tail` of `PTR` element :

```
>>> ptr = r.find('.//PTR')
>>> ptr.tail.strip()
'it'
```